# OsX Python 3.5 Bad Interpreter: no such file or directory

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to run the following code from the terminal window. I am following the tutorial found on this website  https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter6/ . The name of my file is "pw.py" I ran chmod +x pw.py to make it executable from the terminal window. However, when I run ./pw.py I get an error saying  "-bash: ./pw.py: python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory". Any Idea what I missed? Thanks for the help!

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# pw.py - An insecure password locker program.

PASSWORDS = {'email' : 'F7minlBDDuvMJuxESSKHFhTxFtjVB6' ,
             'blog' : 'VmALvQyKAxiVH5G8v01if1MLZF3sdt' ,
             'luggage' : '12345'}
import sys, pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: python pw.py[account] - copy account password')
    sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1]    # first cammand line arg is the account name

if account in PASSWORDS:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
    print('Password for ' + account + ' copied to clipboard.')
else:
    print('There is no account named ' + account)
```

Comment: If /usr/bin/python points to python3.5 I think something is wrong, have you messed with the system python?

Comment: Can you execute simple python scripts from your CLI, example python myscript.py ?

Comment: I dont think I have. What should the shebang line look like?

Comment: Where is your python3.5 installed? You can try /usr/bin/env python3 but the error using /usr/bin/python seems like something is wrong with your system

Comment: python is installed at macintoshHD/applications/python3.5  . Using /usr/bin/env python3 produces the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I was not executing it in the terminal correctly. I was entering './pw.py' when I needed to enter 'python pw.py' in order for it to run the script. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done looks correct from a python perspective.  the `#!` is called a shebang / shabang and it informs the OS what interpreter to call in order to execute this script.

So I would guess that Python is installed in a different location then what has been supplied.  Remember when this is called the full path needs to be supplied.  Try running `which python` to get the location of the interpreter and place that at line 1

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this error when running `pip` python command, this started happening after a system-wide change in $HOME path, which apparently broke some stuff like `pip` (the old $HOME path seems hardcoded somewhere in the python installation).

I fixed it by re-installing pip (following [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)):

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && python get-pip.py
```